# How to show the dropdown values in user defined values?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have list of dropdown values which is dynamically from database and i have to show it as user defined values. how to modify the loop values coming from the foreach and show it in dropdown list.

```
$statuses = wc_get_order_statuses();
```

Output:

```
            Array
(
    [wc-pending] =&gt; Pending Payment
    [wc-processing] =&gt; Processing
    [wc-on-hold] =&gt; On Hold
    [wc-completed] =&gt; Completed
    [wc-cancelled] =&gt; Cancelled
    [wc-refunded] =&gt; Refunded
    [wc-failed] =&gt; Failed
)




            foreach ( $statuses as $status => $status_name ) {
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $status ) . '" ' . '>' . esc_html( $status_name ) . '</option>';
            }
```

How to show it as based on the following order:

```
payment received 
-programming
-approval pending
-production
-shipped 
-cancelled    
-pending payment 
-refunded
-on hold
```

Comment: That does not look like valid output.....

Comment: @gopi are you looking to add custom order statuses and then use them in WP Admin? Your question in current form is very vague.

Comment: Already i have customized the order status in wp admin. i need to show custom order status in particular order